# MySQL: How to make a query between 2 tables that returns NULL to a row that isn't in the 2nd table?

Tags: mysql

I have this 2 tables

1st Table "Users"

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| ID | FirstName | LastName |
+----+-----------+----------+
| 1  | Jeff      | Bezos    |
| 2  | Bill      | Gates    |
| 3  | Elon      | Musk     |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

2nd Table "Records"

```
+----+--------+------------+
| ID | IDUser | RecordDate |
+----+--------+------------+
| 1  | 1      | 15/06/2021 |
| 2  | 2      | 05/06/2021 |
| 3  | 2      | 12/06/2021 |
| 4  | 2      | 02/06/2021 |
| 5  | 1      | 17/06/2021 |
+----+--------+------------+
```

So this 2 tables are linked each other by using a Foreing key Records.IDUsers -> Users.ID

I wanted to make a query that does this

```
+-----------+----------+----------------+--------------------+
| FirstName | LastName | Lastest Record | Numbers of Records |
+-----------+----------+----------------+--------------------+
| Jeff      | Bezos    | 17/06/2021     | 2                  |
| Bill      | Gates    | 12/06/2021     | 3                  |
| Elon      | Musk     | NULL           | NULL               |
+-----------+----------+----------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `LEFT JOIN` in order to get back users without records too; then the `MAX` and `COUNT` aggregate functions.

**First version:** This will return `0` for the number of records instead of `NULL`, when there are no records for a specific user. Latest record will be `NULL` as expected.

```sql
SELECT 
  FirstName,
  LastName,
  MAX(RecordDate) AS LatestRecord,
  COUNT(Records.ID) AS NumberOfRecords
FROM Users LEFT JOIN Records on Users.ID = Records.IDUser
GROUP BY Users.ID;
```

If you want `NULL` instead of `0` (which normally you do *not* want), you can use the `IF` function like this:

```sql
SELECT 
  FirstName,
  LastName,
  MAX(RecordDate) AS LatestRecord,
  IF(COUNT(Records.ID) > 0, COUNT(Records.ID), NULL) AS NumberOfRecords
FROM Users LEFT JOIN Records on Users.ID = Records.IDUser
GROUP BY Users.ID;
```

**Second version:** It might happen that running the above query will return an error, something like:

> Error: ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP: ...; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

This happens when/if the [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) SQL mode is enabled (which it is by default since MySQL 5.7.5). In order to get around this error, you can use the `ANY_VALUE` function to select the nonaggregated fields:

```sql
SELECT 
  ANY_VALUE(FirstName) AS FirstName,
  ANY_VALUE(LastName) AS LastName,
  MAX(RecordDate) AS LatestRecord,
  COUNT(Records.ID) AS NumberOfRecords
FROM Users LEFT JOIN Records on Users.ID = Records.IDUser
GROUP BY Users.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

left join select all user even if does not have records

```
select * from users left join records on records.IDUser = ID;
```